# Equivalent of VB.NET WaitOne() & Set() in Delphi

Tags: vb.net, delphi

Could anyone tell me what's the equivalent of this vb code in Delphi ?

Do I need to use:

```
ResetMyEvent: THandle; //??
```

These VB lines copied from a small console app.  No visual components.

Thank you.

```
Module MyModule
  Private WithEvents Obj As MyInterface
  Private WaitForStartLibrary As AutoResetEvent = New AutoResetEvent(False)

Sub Main()
  Obj.StartLibrary(param1, param2,...)

  If WaitForStartLibrary.WaitOne(5000) = False Then//How can I do this w/out timer comp ?
    Throw New Exception("Operation timed out")
  End If
End Sub

//Event
Private Sub StartLibraryCallBack() Handles Obj.StartLibraryCallBack
  WaitForStartLibrary.Set()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

The Delphi equivalent to the .net `AutoResetEvent` is [`TEvent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SyncObjs.TEvent).

- When you [create](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SyncObjs.TEvent.Create) it pass `False` for the `ManualReset` argument which will give you an auto reset event.
- To wait on the event, call [`WaitFor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SyncObjs.THandleObject.WaitFor).
- To set the event, call [`SetEvent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SyncObjs.TEvent.SetEvent).

Comment: Thank you very much.

The VB code is very elegant & I'd like to achieve the same in Delphi but not sure how.
I have no threads in my application at this moment.
Looked at your answer & I'm using these lines but not sure how to put everything together to get the same result as the VB code:
    WaitForStartLibrary:= TEvent.Create(nil, false, false, '');
    WaitForStartLibrary.WaitFor(5000);// App hangs here!
  (Code in StartLibraryCallBack event)
   WaitForStartLibrary.SetEvent;
I would be grateful if you give me an example.
Thanks you.